# Multisite plugin hiding on specific blogs

Tags: multisite

Is it possible to hide plugins on a per blog basis in WordPress multisite? I would like not to have plugins available on certain blogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Super Admin is your friend!](http://codex.wordpress.org/Super_Admin_Admin_Screen)  If a plugin is not active in the Super Admin (also lamely named Network Admin) Then it won't show up as an option for individual blogs.

**It basically works like this:**

Installed as Super Admin (main site) and "Network Active" will be active on all blogs on the network. 
Installed on Super Admin, Active but **NOT** "Network Active" only active on Main/Parent site

If you want it only installed on a few sites then just manually install the plugins like you would normally do. Each instance of WordPress on a multisite is treated as its own site so installing a plugin on one site (with the exception of the main site) will not install it on the rest.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments I would make sure that the user has the correct role to upload/activate plugins. You must create a user in each site individually or add an existing user to the site.

You could also try a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-plugin-manager/ and see how it goes.

Comment: Hmm that's not what I'm seeing. Installing a plugin and not activating it in Network admin, makes it available for activation in all individual blogs.

Comment: From the individual blogs I cannot search for or upload any plugins. And I see all plugins installed via Network admin, whether activated there or not.

Comment: See Edit and let me know if that helps.